# call a variable that is declared within a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, google-chrome-extension

I have used message passing in my chrome extension to move data from the background.js to the content.js file.

Within the function below when I output the variable to the console within the function I get the data I expect. When I try the same outside of the function I get null (as defined in the global variable).

Does anyone have an idea how I can pull the data out of the function so I can post it with my AJAX call.

**Code**

```
var capturedData = "url=" + window.location.href;
var localHash = "localhash=" + CryptoJS.MD5(capturedData);
var email = null;

chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    email = response;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(email));
    return true;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(email));


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: {"url":capturedData, "localhash":localHash},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (data) {
        if(data.url)
        {
            console.log(data.url);
        }  
    }
});
```

**Output**

> null content.js:10  {"email":"email@email.com"} content.js:7

Thanks!

Comment: You can't (or you really don't want to). You should make the AJAX call from inside the first callback. Just throw your AJAX call in a function, then invoke it in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your ajax call after you get some value on email:

```
var capturedData = "url=" + window.location.href;
var localHash = "localhash=" + CryptoJS.MD5(capturedData);
var email = null;

chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    email = response;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(email));


$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: {"url":capturedData, "localhash":localHash},
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (data) {
       if(data.url)
       {
        console.log(data.url);
       }  
    }
 });

return true;
});

 console.log(JSON.stringify(email));
```